# Why are the IDFV and IDFA available even if I limit ad tracking?

Tags: ios, ios7, settings, privacy

I'm getting the Identifier for Advertiser and Identifier for Vendor, but am a little confused about the effects of a setting.

```
[[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString] // Don't forget to #import <AdSupport/ASIdentifierManager.h>
[[[UIDevice  currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]
```

They both get me the IDs, which is confusing when I toggle the setting below.

*Settings > Privacy > Limit Ad Tracking*

I would think that toggling that would affect my ability to retrieve those IDs. This makes me wonder if I'm missing something, so I have to ask: **why isn't the IDFV and IDFA retrieval affected by the option to Limit Ad Tracking?** Is it supposed to be affected at all?

Answer (score 0):

What is affected is the value you get by calling the `isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled`. You can check it by calling `isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled` method of `ASIdentifierManager`.

> **isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled**
>
> Check the value of this property before performing any advertising
>   tracking. If the value is `NO`, use the advertising identifier only for
>   the following purposes: frequency capping, conversion events,
>   estimating the number of unique users, security and fraud detection,
>   and debugging.

The following code snippet shows how to obtain a string value of `IDFA`.

```
- (NSString *)identifierForAdvertising
{
   if([[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] isAdvertisingTrackingEnabled])
   {
       NSUUID *IDFA = [[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier];

       return [IDFA UUIDString];
   }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that you cannot access IDFA when Limit ad tracking is enabled.
Limit ad tracking simply 'limits' the advanced advertising behavior - Re-targeting,behavioural targeting,negative targeting, etc.. but it doesn't still say that a conversion tracking(simple app installation) is limited.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 10.0, the advertising identifier is all zeroes when limit ad tracking is enabled.

From the documentation:

> In iOS 10.0 and later, the value of advertisingIdentifier is all
>   zeroes when the user has limited ad tracking.